# MySQL query ordering data two ways

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am tracking page views within modules using the following table:

```
id | page_id | user_id | session_id | created
```

Every page is unique to a certain module; so page 14 only exists in module 2, for instance.

I am trying to write a query that tells me when a viewing session began (GROUP BY session_id) for a particular module, but I am having trouble with my ordering. Basically, for that grouped session, I want to return the earliest 'created' (the starting time of the viewing session) and the latest page_id (how far they got within the module).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and the desired resultset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to utilise sub-queries in the select:

```
SELECT a.session_id, MIN(a.created) as start_time, 
b.page_id AS last_page, b.end_time
FROM table a 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT b.session_id, MAX(b.created) as end_time, MAX(b.page_id) 
   FROM table b GROUP BY b.session_id) 
ON a.session_id = b.session_id GROUP BY a.session_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  MIN(created), MAX(page_id)
FROM    modules
GROUP BY
        session_id
```

Comment: I don't believe that will show the desired results - the MAX(page_id) I think needs to correspond to the last created time.

Comment: @BrynJ: Based on the OP's definition of "how far they got within the module" @Quassnoi would still be right.